# how to implement multiple local notification not a single notification for swift 3

Tags: notifications, swift3, ios10, localnotification

i have use the single notification , and this is my code:
this is for register the local notification>>>

```
    func registerLocal() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Yay!")
        } else {
            print("D'oh")
        }
    }
}
```

and this function to schedule the local notification>>>

```
func scheduleLocal() {
    registerCategories()

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    // not required, but useful for testing!
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "good morning"
    content.body = "ttt123"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 23
    dateComponents.minute = 18
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}

func registerCategories() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self

    let show = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "show", title: "Tell me more…", options: .foreground)
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alarm", actions: [show], intentIdentifiers: [])

    center.setNotificationCategories([category])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // pull out the buried userInfo dictionary
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let customData = userInfo["customData"] as? String {
        print("Custom data received: \(customData)")

        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            // the user swiped to unlock; do nothing
            print("Default identifier")

        case "show":
            print("Show more information…")
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // you need to call the completion handler when you're done
    completionHandler()
}
```

now how can i use this code with the multiple local notification with iOS 10 and different times 
thank you .

Comment: So, did you find a solution for your case? :)

Answer (score 14):

Use a different request identifier for each notification (otherwise you only see the last notification). 
In the above example, ensure request identifier "UUID().uuidString" contains a unique value for each notification request.

Answer (score 14):

You can call the `func scheduleLocal()` multiple times with different `dateComponents` to schedule on different dates. Or you can pass a array of dates to this function and run a loop to schedule the notifications according to these dates.

Just make sure that the identifier you pass in  `UNNotificationRequest(identifier:, content:, trigger:)` function is different for each notification.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: "Make sure to Set unique identifier for each notification" This was my mistake...  +1

Answer (score 2):

Call this function with different parameters. Like i called when app goes background

```
  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        setNotification(time: 25,identifier: "notific2")
        setNotification(time: 50,identifier: "notific3")
        setNotification(time: 90,identifier: "notific4")
    }


  func setNotification (time : Int,identifier : String)
    {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Don't forget"
        content.body = "Buy some milk"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(time),
                                                        repeats: false)
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        // Swift
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                            content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your code should works as expected! however, there is a little pitfall.

I think that I almost faced the *exact* same issue, after I tried to trace the pending notifications, I noted that the only notification that has been added is the last requested one. That's because you are calling in `scheduleLocal()` function:

```
// not required, but useful for testing!
center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

Well, it is good to remove any existing notification reminder requests, this would help preventing unnecessary duplicate notifications, but you should call it *only once* before calling `scheduleLocal()`:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
// now you could call this function many times...
scheduleLocal()
```

simply, you don't want to delete each pending notification directly after adding it, instead you delete the whole previous pending notifications and add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple local notification than you have to used different identifier for each request.

```
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Stock Changed", content: content, trigger: nil)
```

Change "Stock Changed" with your different identifier for each request.

You can use loop for multiple request.